# Puppeteer - Remove function exposed by exposeFunction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I am using the exposeFunction-command in the following manner:

```
await this.page.exposeFunction('foo', function(){ return 'bar'; });
```

This works as intended and gives me the window.foo-function.

If I call this code again, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to add page binding with name foo: window['foo'] already exists!
```

This error even persists when navigating with page.goto().

Is there a way to unbind a function exposed by exposeFunction()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the function stored in the `_pageBindings` map. This is quite hacky because you would change an internal variable, but it's the only way to solve this.

```js
await this.page.exposeFunction('foo', function(){ return 'bar'; }); 
this.page._pageBindings.set('foo', function(){ return 'baz'; });
```

Comment: Is there any downside to directly changing the internal variable? does it affect like the performance? sorry beginner here.

Comment: @vexingCoder the risk is that's not part of the API. So the puppeteer can rename `_pageBindings` if they need to, breaking your code.

Comment: oh i see thank you so much. so if ever puppeteer changed it i couldnt update my puppeteer version. cause it would break my code thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use try and catch. so if the function is exposed it will throw error in catch. Something like this.

```
try {
   await page.exposeFunction('yourfunction', () => {return 'somethin'})
} catch (err)  {
   //the error will be catched, so no worries cheers!
}
```